# Characters returned as question marks in command prompt, but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, command, prompt

When I attempt to run my program in my command prompt (Windows 7), some of the text that is returned is turned into question marks. I thought I had solved the issue by adding "UTF-8" to my BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

Which seems to work in Eclipse, but not in **cmd.exe**. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you know what format cmd.exe use in default?  This is some information about change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8: http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

Comment: Does the font used in your Command Prompt window support the characters you're returning?

Comment: The code change you made, meant that the file was properly decoded but the problem is that cmd.exe uses 8bit code pages by default. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500